# Polynomial Regression sensible in case with 6 cross-sectional points of experience?

Tags: regression, likert, polynomial, psychology, cross-section

I have a dataset of 300 cases of police students, spread over 6 semesters. They all filled out a survey at the same time (cross section), thus their experience is interval scaled since semester 1 means approximately 6 months of studies and every further semester has each 6 additional months.

I have an integrity measure (7-point Likert scale) and found out, that integrity is lower for those in 2nd and 5th semester (which are practical semesters).

**Edit: I calculated an aggregated value over 11 situations which are judged on a 7-point Likert scale.**

I calculated a stepwise polynomial regression and came to the conclusion, that one with a 4th degree fits the data best.

```
Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-1.77130 -0.31675 -0.02838  0.34768  1.50143 

Coefficients:
                                         Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)                               7.94414    0.85978   9.240  < 2e-16 ***
data$data_crosssection_complete.SEM      -4.44345    1.41442  -3.142  0.00185 ** 
I(data$data_crosssection_complete.SEM^2)  2.18171    0.72026   3.029  0.00267 ** 
I(data$data_crosssection_complete.SEM^3) -0.42178    0.14460  -2.917  0.00380 ** 
I(data$data_crosssection_complete.SEM^4)  0.02807    0.01001   2.804  0.00538 ** 
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.5719 on 297 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.03747,   Adjusted R-squared:  0.02451 
F-statistic: 2.891 on 4 and 297 DF,  p-value: 0.0226
```

Thing is, I am not sure, if I am allowed to do that. My doctor mother has not worked with polynomial regression, so she can't help me and suggested I should find studies which used one, preferably in the field of organisational psychology (am still searching). And she said the variance is too small, which I am not sure, what that means in my case. Is it that I only have 6 fixed points? How could I work around this?

Edit:
Here are my boxplots:
[image]

Comment: What exactly is your model? Are you treating your integrity measure as continuous or ordinal? If I understand what you've done correctly, I think that with 6 semesters you'd be much better off treating semester as categorical rather than fitting a 4th degree polynomial.

Comment: I treat the integrity measure as continuously, yes.

Comment: Okay, thanks. Is this because of the lacking in variance?

Comment: About the 'variance is too small' comment, I suspect she meant that the variance *explained* (i.e. $R^2$) is very small, as I wrote in my answer.

Comment: Based on your new boxplot, I have an additional concern: there are values depicted that are in between 3 and 4, which indicates that this is *not* ordinal data like a Likert scale. Were you averaging different values to get the integrity measure?

Comment: @mkt Yes, I am sorry. Still confusing to get back into statistics. I calculated a mean over 11 situations with a 7-point-Likert-scale each. So this is an aggregated value.

Comment: Okay, there are some assumptions in there that I can't comment on without more information but that may be fine. For future reference this kind of information is worth adding in the question.

Comment: @mkt I added that to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've used several parameters in your polynomial and the pattern you describe (low integrity in 2nd and 5th semester) is very odd and contrary to reasonable expectation. In this situation, I think you'd be much better off treating `semester` as a categorical variable and not continuous.

Other concerns:

1. Your model explains just ~3% of the variance ($R^2$), which is very low.
2. You are treating your integrity measure as continuous instead of ordinal. This may be reasonable but is worth thinking about.

**EDIT** based on the information that 2nd and 5th semesters are meaningfully different:

I would still be inclined to treat semester as categorical if you want to make a simple model that only includes semester. But if you are willing to consider building more complex models, you could could account for practical/university semesters with a factor and use a simpler continuous time trend for semester (I would starting by considering just a linear relationship).

Comment: The pattern is actually very in line with expectations since semesters 2 and 5 are practical semesters, where the police students go out on the streets and are socialised by their future peers. Semsters 1, 3, 4 and 6 are semesters at the university with different socialization.

Comment: I realize the explained variance is very low. A multilevel analysis would be the next step (gender, city, ...).

Comment: @Tim That is an interesting point about practical semesters. I would still be inclined to treat `semester` as categorical if you want to make a simple model such as this. If you want to consider building more complex models, you could could account for practical/university semesters with a factor and use a simpler continuous time trend for semester (maybe just linear).

Comment: Ah, yes. That seems like a much cleaner approach. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Tim You're welcome. I have updated the answer based on this new information to include the information in my comment.